# htaccess rewrite not working

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite `http://example.com/apps/app4/step1.php` to `http://easyfanpageapp.com/apps/`

I have used this rewrite but it's not working.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule    ^apps/?$    ^(.*)\step1.php$   [NC,L]
```

Also tried

```
RewriteRule    ^apps/?$     apps/app4/step1.php$   [NC,L]
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule that does what you ask is:

```
RewriteRule ^apps apps/app4/step1.php [NC,L]
```

Depending on your app, you may want more:

```
RewriteRule ^apps(.*) apps/app4/step1.php?args=$1 [NC,L]
```